# Read tuple key and value

Tags: erlang, tuples, data-retrieval

How can I read a tuple key and value in Erlang?

I have this variable:

```
Params = [<<"TPUIBrowser">>,0,18,
 {[{<<"End">>,<<"location-1Ã¿">>},{<<"Start">>,<<"location-1">>}]},
 null]
```

and I would like to get the values for `<<"End">>` and `<<"Start">>`.

How could I do that in Erlang?

I can do it like this:

```
[_,_,_,A,_] = Params.
{[{_,B},{_,C}]} = A.
```

But this feels very verbose and error prone (i.e. when I get sent more params). What would be the best *erlang* way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions for this in the [lists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) library. Check out [lists:keyfind](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#keyfind-3):

```
[_,_,_,{A},_] = Params,
{Key, Value} = lists:keyfind(<<"End">>, 1, A).
```

(I assume you know where in `Params` you have `A`)

Comment: When I try this, I get this error:

{Key, Value} = lists:keyfind(<<"End">>, 1, A).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  lists:keyfind/3
        called as lists:keyfind(<<"End">>,1,
                                {[{<<"End">>,<<"location-1Ã¿">>},
                                  {<<"Start">>,<<"location-1">>}]})

Comment: Oh, I missed that your list was inside a one-element-tuple. I've fixed my answer (and actually tried it this time :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [records](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#records) which are particularly suitable if you plan to add more fields.

Since you use a list here `{[{_,B},{_,C}]} = A.` I assume that there might be more elements; in this case, making a recursive function to unpack it could be better.